# How do i pull the next 2 words after a specific string?

Tags: sql, substring, charindex, patindex

I am spending a long time on how to pull part of a long string in T-SQL. I need to pull the person after "Eaten by" string. In this case, the first string below will be **Smith, John** and for the second string it will be **Bloggs, Joe**

Each string length is never the same, however the spacing is always consistent.
I don't know whether to use SUBSTRING,CHARINDEX or PATINDEX or a combination of these, I have attempted all these, but been unsuccessful.

**Example String 1**
'Apple: Two days Pear: Three days Banana: One day Eaten by: Smith, John Location 1: First Street Location 2: Second Street'

**Example String 2**
'Pear: Three days Banana: One day Eaten by: Bloggs, Joe Location 1: First Street Location 2: Second Street Location 3: Third Street'

Any help with be appreciated. Thanks.

P

```
SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@string,charindex('Eaten by:',@string) + LEN('Eaten by:'), LEN(@string)), 2, CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(@string,charindex('Eaten by:',@string) + LEN('Eaten by:'), LEN(@string)), CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(@string,charindex('Eaten by:',@string) + LEN('Eaten by:'), LEN(@string)), 2)+1))
```

The output was:

`Smith, John Location 1: First Street Location 2: Second Street`

I need "Smith, John' only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a better solution out there but I'm just using the code that you provided: you can use a combination of `LTRIM()` and `RTRIM()` for *SQL Server 2016* to trim whitespaces. I also adjusted your first inner `SUBSTRING()` from `2` to `1` to get the results that you're looking for:

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR (4000)
SET @string = 'Apple: Two days Pear: Three days Banana: One day Eaten by: Smith, John Location 1: First Street Location 2: Second Street'
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@string,charindex('Eaten by:',@string) + LEN('Eaten by:'), LEN(@string)), 1, CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(@string,charindex('Eaten by:',@string) + LEN('Eaten by:'), LEN(@string)), CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(@string,charindex('Eaten by:',@string) + LEN('Eaten by:'), LEN(@string)), 2)+1)))) AS Name;
```

**Result:**

| Name |
| --- |
| Smith, John |

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR (4000)
SET @string = 'Pear: Three days Banana: One day Eaten by: Bloggs, Joe Location 1: First Street Location 2: Second Street Location 3: Third Street'
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@string,charindex('Eaten by:',@string) + LEN('Eaten by:'), LEN(@string)), 1, CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(@string,charindex('Eaten by:',@string) + LEN('Eaten by:'), LEN(@string)), CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(@string,charindex('Eaten by:',@string) + LEN('Eaten by:'), LEN(@string)), 2)+1)))) AS Name;
```

**Result:**

| Name |
| --- |
| Bloggs, Joe |

**Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/B0dPVcjA).**

**Note:** It goes without saying, but I'll mention it anyways: you should consider upgrading your SQL Server to the latest version. Besides new features (like `TRIM()`), there are also security vulnerabilities in the older versions that can be exploited amongst a variety of other reasons.

### **UPDATE:**

I now realize the end of your string is not a whitespace but rather a Line Feed `LF` represented by `CHAR(10)` ASCII [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/char-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

I've also added a `subquery` to get the string value for both middle and end of string scenarios with a `CASE` statement to check for a blank value; alternatively, you can use a `CTE` (see fiddle).

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN LocationMiddle = '' THEN LocationEnd 
  ELSE LocationMiddle END AS Name
  FROM (
 SELECT 
    LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@string,charindex('Requested by:',@string) + LEN('Requested by:'), LEN(@string)), 1, CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), SUBSTRING(@string,charindex('Requested by:',@string) + LEN('Requested by:'), LEN(@string)), CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(@string,charindex('Requested by:',@string) + LEN('Requested by:'), LEN(@string)), 2)+1)))) AS LocationMiddle,
    LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@string,CHARINDEX('Requested by:',@string)+LEN('Requested by:'),LEN(@string)))) AS LocationEnd
  ) A;
```

**Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/WyEKaVbs).**